# Working around Android/Java Pattern/Matcher Regex very long string limit

Tags: android, regex, string

I am parsing very long svg paths. So all svg commands are properly matched and their data is extracted. But, it basically just passes when I have a very long string. Namely a string 352,742 characters. ( http://pastebin.com/c5XqpS3d )

```
(?i)[csqtamlzhvxkf](?:[^/csqtamlzhvxkf]|/[^/]*/)*
```

For the regex for the commandParser, it works for shorter strings but when given a string that long it just sort of skips. Even though the string clearly begins:

> M 740.4895,514.99567 711.3773,501.32477...

Obviously any string starting with M will match. But, match.find() simply returns false, and says there's nothing there.

```
    Matcher match = commandParser.matcher(path);
    while (match.find()) {
        int start = match.start();
        values.reset();
        values.ops = path.subSequence(start + 1, match.end());
        String command = path.substring(start,start+1);
        if (parser.matched(command,values)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Is it something with the platform (Android)? Or weirdly limited somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the alternation group that causes redundant backtracking. If the `/[^/]*/` is rare in your string, unroll the pattern as

```
(?i)[csqtamlzhvxkf](?:[^/csqtamlzhvxkf]*(?:/[^/]*/[^/csqtamlzhvxkf]*)*)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/niLANj/1)

It will match:

- `[csqtamlzhvxkf]` -  a letter form the set
- `(?:[^/csqtamlzhvxkf]*(?:/[^/]*/[^/csqtamlzhvxkf]*)*)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `[^/csqtamlzhvxkf]*` - 0+ chars other than those in the set
  - `(?:/[^/]*/[^/csqtamlzhvxkf]*)*` - 0+ sequences of:

    - `/[^/]*/` - `/` followed with 0+ chars other than `/` and a `/`
    - `[^/csqtamlzhvxkf]*` - 0+ chars other than those in the set